# Скрипт на perl перегружает запросами базу MySQL

Tags: mysql, perl, веб-программирование

```
SELECT id, zagol, datetime_show FROM knia_news WHERE enabled='yes' ORDER
BY datetime_show DESC, id DESC LIMIT 12300, 25;
```

Вот так выглядит запрос к базе MySQL.

А вот так выглядит область кода формирующая запрос к базе MySQL и затем выводит результат в цикле.

```
if($page eq '1'){$page1 = 0;} else {$page1=$mess*$page-$mess;}

            $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq{SELECT id, zagol, datetime_show FROM }.$mysql_table_name.qq{news WHERE enabled='yes' ORDER BY datetime_show DESC, id DESC LIMIT $page1, $mess}); $sth->execute();
            while(my ($id, $zagol, $datetime_show) = $sth->fetchrow_array())
            {
            ($date,$time) = split(/ /,$datetime_show);
            $date =~ /^(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)$/;
            $date = "$3.$2.$1";


            print qq{
            <tr>
            <td width="9%" align="left" valign="top">$date</td>
            <td width="91%"><p><a href="/news/$id.html">$zagol <img src="/img/1.gif" width="9" height="9" border="0"></a></p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            };
            }
```

При обращении к базе , эта область кода совершает перебор базы, что бы выдать 25 результатов.

Подскажите где проблема в конкретном случае?

Comment: `if($page eq '1'){$page1 = 0;} else {$page1=$mess*$page-$mess;}`  == `$page1=($page-1)*$mess;` :)  И старайтесь использовать привязываемые переменные `prepare(.... limit ?,?); $sth->execute($page1, $mess)` 492 страница которую у вас запросили конечно сильно, но непосредственные значения в запросе так же чуть чуть медленнее, за счет невозможности кеширования плана СУБД и + возможность sql-инъекции, если mess не проверяете на число.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в LIMIT 12300, 25 - на любой базе данных потребуется перебрать 12300 x 25 элементов. Предположу, что у вас в постраничной навигации есть пункт с последним элементом, на которые щелкают посетители и которая доступна роботам. На таких больших массивах данных, стараются прятать этот последний, чтобы добраться до страницы, генерирующий этот запрос было сложно. Если там вообще нет интересных данных, можно в принципе отсечь их, например, сделав offset 12300, не больше 50, т.е. чтобы не ввел пользователь - уменьшайте его до какого-то разумного предела.

Comment: Действительно. Постраничная навигация присутствует. Сейчас попытаюсь разобраться в этом кошмаре. Спасибо.

Comment: К сожалению навигация построена по другому принципу. Показывается 5 ссылок на страницы с новостями до текущей страницы и после. Ссылки на последнюю страницу нет.

Comment: В любом случае следует поискать откуда такой большой оффсет. Особенно, если запросов много. Урезать его на уровне бэкенда - все еще вариант, конечно, от данных еще много зависит.

Answer (score 1):

Самый лучший вариант - привязываться к дате заметки. То есть не постранично, а листать "предыдущий день".
В этом случае LIMIT исключается, но со стороны сервера потребуется дополнительная проверка "если новостей а этот день не было, расширить зону поиска".
Можно объединить эти два подхода - выводить, к примеру новости за месяц, при этом постранично, по 25.

```
SELECT id, zagol, datetime_show FROM knia_news WHERE enabled='yes' 
     AND datetime_show BETWEEN $date and DATE_ADD($date,INTERVAL 7 DAY)
ORDER BY datetime_show DESC, id DESC;
```

И не забудьте проверить, чтобы по полю enabled и datetime_show был индекс.

Comment: У меня тоже возникло подозрение на отсутствие индексов. Сейчас полезу проверять.